# javascript progress bar with clicking

Tags: javascript

Hi I need a progress bar which updates every 0.1s filling by 0.1% and also filling by 1% when clicked on any place on the site. I already have this, but I can't make it fill by clicking. I'm trying for so long without any progress.

```js
                var i = 0;
                function move() {
                    
                    if (i == 0) {
                        i = 1;
                        var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
                        var width = 1;
                        var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
                        
                        
                        
                        function frame() {
                            if (width >= 100) {
                                clearInterval(id);
                                i = 0;
                            } 
                            else {
                                width+=0.1;
                                elem.style.width = width + "%";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

```html
        <div id="myProgress">
            <div id="myBar"></div>
        </div>
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: Hi, I think you use the `frame` function too soon, try to call it after the declaration of the frame function

Comment: Doesn't work or I did it wrong. :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create event listener on `click` and increment `width` value by one.

```js
elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
  width += 1;
})
```

Comment: I've tried it, it either doesn't work or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: So.. what's wrong? Any errors? Do you have this part of code inside move function?

Comment: https://jsbin.com/libabetucu/1/edit?js,console,output
Here is a working example based on your code. Ofc it's not clean code etc. but I'm trying to make your code work.